# Conditionals of signed measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory

My question pertains the definition of regular conditional measures of signed measures defined on product spaces.

Consider a Suslin measurable space $\mathcal A=X\times Y$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal A$. I am interested in the decomposition of $\mu$ in the following form $$d\mu=d\nu(x\mid y)\,d\bar \mu(y).$$

Such a decomposition is possible for both signed and unsigned measures (refer Bogachev). For the particular case when $\mu$ is unsigned, one could argue that $\nu(\cdot \mid y)$ is technically the same as that of the conditional probability measure derived by normalizing $\mu$; i.e. let $\hat \mu=\mu/\|\mu\|$ and consider the decomposition
$$d\hat\mu=d\nu(x\mid y)\,d\hat{\bar\mu}(y)$$
where $$\hat{\bar \mu}(A)\,\|\mu\|=\bar\mu(A),\> A\subset Y$$
and $\nu(\cdot\mid y)$ is a probability conditional measure for each $y\in Y$.

In the above, $\bar \mu$ can be seen as the y-marginal of $\mu$.

->Now onto the interesting case -- signed measures.

Theorem 10.4.14 of Bogachev gives a decomposition of the signed measure $\mu_s$ in terms of the total variation of $\mu_s$, $|\mu_s|$, as follows
$$d\mu_s =d\nu_s(x\mid y)\,d\overline{|\mu_s|}(y),$$
where $\overline{|\mu_s|}$ is the y-marginal of $|\mu_s|$.

### Question :

Can we say something to the effect that either $\nu_s(\cdot\mid y)$ or $-\nu_s(\cdot\mid y)$ is a conditional probability measure on the generated sub-sigma algebra?

[Bogachev] Bogachev, Vladimir I., *Measure Theory*, Springer, 2007